# Jquery img added through append() triggers onload twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, image, onload

The code that produces the headache for me is rather simple:

```
$(function(){ 
$("#test").append('<img onload="alert(\'hi\')" src="Image.jpg"/>');
})
```

I have the above code in my head and a div with id 'test' in the body. Now my problem is that the page produces two alerts when the image is loaded, but I expected it to produce only one as the 'onload' should be triggered only once- The way it happens when I add the image manually without any javascript..
See the fiddle I made at: http://jsfiddle.net/9985N/

Any help/explanation is greatly appreciated...

Comment: Using `.html(...)` method will fix it, but I have no idea why is this happening

Comment: May be offtopic, but you should never attach `load` on images.

Comment: @Jashwant: Could you explain why? 'coz I dint see w3c guys mention anything about that at :http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_img_onload.asp

Comment: First see this [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/) and then [jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Comment: w3shools may not provide good stuff for learning but its good for element reference,about the caveats mentioned @ jquery api site -seems reasonable but that doesn't mean we should 'never' use it (as I understand it)...The only feature I required here was cross-browser compatibility and it seems fine with most modern browsers
(for example: I don't want the function to be called if the image is cached..)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> UPDATED (Because some people don't believe me, lol)

Because `.append` creates the node first and then moves it to its appropriate position. Try appending the element first then adding its attributes as follow:

```
$(function() {
    $("#test").append(
        $("<img />").attr({
            src: "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1a/Bachalpseeflowers.jpg/300px-Bachalpseeflowers.jpg",
            onload: "alert(\'hi\')"
        })
    );
});
```

My answer does not "avoid" the problem, it answers it very directly.  If you open the jQuery.js file in uncompressed format you can clearly see that `.append` creates the `node` on the document which is when the `onload` event is first called and then `shifts` it into position which is when it gets called again. Perhaps shift is the wrong word, forgive me as vocabulary is not my strong suit.  However if you follow the code you see its creation and its movement, however the same is not said for using append again to move it, as the node is already created it simply moves from one element to another with no respark of onload.  As I said, not sure best terminology, but it's very easy to follow along on the [jQuery.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js).

Don't believe me? Just tested the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/uGraS/) in MSIE9, FF12, & GoogleChrome20 with 0 problems.

## ***jsFiddle***

just FYI, it's not really a horrible practice, but I see people write whole lines of HTML in jQuery all the time and that kind of defeats the purpose.  It's a library with many books to read on purpose.  Sometimes a complete line of HTML might seem easier, but it may not be faster as it doesn't follow all the great layout work that has been done for you. The idea is to "Write less, do more" and this includes HTML.  After all, if you were gonna write the whole line of HTML, why use jQuery at all when you could just PHP it in!? :P Just a thought.

Comment: -1 Your answer avoids the problem. Actually the alert is showing twice even without appending the object anywhere ... just by wrapping it inside `$('<img...')`. [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/teneff/9985N/11/)

Comment: Why would `append` shift it if its the only element ?

Comment: @tenneff:great point- unfortunately it increases the confussion even more- is this a jquery bug?

Comment: btw, moving the image wont trigger the 'onload' again, would it?

Comment: wow,the update really clarifies stuff, but still would you care to explain what happens when we write $('<img...') as Teneff said?

Answer (score 0):

or this:

```
var img = $('<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1a/Bachalpseeflowers.jpg/300px-Bachalpseeflowers.jpg"/>').on('load', function(){
    $('#test').append(img);
    alert('loaded');  
});
```

Comment: Slightly different from the problem-your code appends when the image is loaded, right? (I was talking about the reverse)