# jQuery Img Load Not Firing When Img Appended

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816053/jquery-img-added-through-append-triggers-onload-twice), but instead of `load` being hit twice, for me it isn't being hit at all. Based on the accepted answer to that question, I have this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zoxicapo/1/edit):

```
$('#goButton').click(function(e){
  $('#hello').empty();
  $('#hello').append($('<img />').attr({ 
    src: "http://www.vision-call.co.uk/images/stories/events/sample.jpg",
    onload: "alert('hello');"
  }));  
});


$('img').load(function() {
  alert("jquery");
});
```

I am seeing the `onload` alert, but not the jQuery `load` alert, can anybody explain why this is? It works fine if I have the `img` in the `HTML` to begin with, but isn't hitting when I add it via jQuery `append`. In my "true" logic, I don't have the javascript `onload` attribute defined, I only have the jQuery `load` set up, and my initial attempts at this demo followed that same logic, which is what I'd ideally want. I know I could just hook up the `onload` to a function, but I'd rather use this event handler.

I assume this is something simple I am missing, but it seems like somebody else will have to point it out to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$('img') is non existent. You addded the img after the button is clicked and you cannont attach the listener before.

```
$('#goButton').click(function(e){
  $('#hello').empty();
  var newImage = $('<img />').attr({ 
    src: "http://www.vision-call.co.uk/images/stories/events/sample.jpg",
    onload: "alert('hello');"
  }).on('load', function() {
    alert("jquery");
  });

  $('#hello').append(newImage);
});
```

Fixed demo: [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zoxicapo/3/edit)

Answer (score 1):

If you read the jQuery api, there are problems with this event and images: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Here is what it says:

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load() shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with this that should be noted. These are:
>
> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> - Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

Comment: Thanks for the info, that was enough to scare me away from using this in prod code since I have an acceptable alternative.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to try `promise` and `done`

```
$('#goButton').click(function(e){
  $('#hello').empty();
  $('#hello').append($('<img />').attr({ 
    src: "http://www.vision-call.co.uk/images/stories/events/sample.jpg",
    onload: "alert('hello');"
  })).promise().done(function(){alert("jquery");});  
});
```

http://jsbin.com/zoxicapo/6/

Answer (score 0):

*Edited*

Briefly tested / was working, seems to be inconsistent across multiple platforms. Need to look further into this.

Your `img` doesn't exist at the time you call the `.load()`. However, why not just do something like this?

```
$('#goButton').click(function(e){
    $('#hello').empty();
    $('#hello').append($('<img />').attr({ 
        src: "http://www.vision-call.co.uk/images/stories/events/sample.jpg",
        onload: "loader()"
    }));  
});

var loader = function() {
    alert('hello');
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `()` from `"loader()"`? you aren't wanting to call the method, just set the handler, right?